# Query with Multiple subqueries is making my system hang

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I have written a query where there is a file with people's names. And each person has a family ID. So multiple members of the same family will all have the same ID.

I have written a query that first lists the family ID then all family members on the same output line.

---

i.e.

ID39874 John Smith Harry Smith Jane Smith

---

I have some families with over 9 family members. My following query works great in testing a small file with a few records.  But when I run the query with the file having over 20,000 records, my system hangs tremendously. I know my system is getting killed because of so many subqueries, but for testing, i just could not figure out any other way of approaching this.

Can anyone suggest another way of approaching this without killing my system.  Thanks

Note - I know I have 8 subqueries to cover families with up to 9 family members. Any family with less than 9 members just outputs the members as null values, so I am Ok with that result.

---

### Working Query:

```
select v.family_id, v.full_name, 
    (select b.full_name 
        from family_table b 
        where v.family_id = b.family_id 
        LIMIT 1,1) as voter_02,
    (select c.full_name 
        from family_table c 
        where v.family_id = c.family_id 
        LIMIT 2,1) as voter_03,
    (select d.full_name 
        from family_table d 
        where v.family_id = d.family_id 
        LIMIT 3,1) as voter_04,
    (select e.full_name 
        from family_table e 
        where v.family_id = e.family_id 
        LIMIT 4,1) as voter_05,
    (select f.full_name 
        from family_table f 
        where v.family_id = f.family_id 
        LIMIT 5,1) as voter_06,
    (select g.full_name 
        from family_table g 
        where v.family_id = g.family_id 
        LIMIT 6,1) as voter_07,
    (select h.full_name 
        from family_table h 
        where v.family_id = h.family_id 
        LIMIT 7,1) as voter_08,
    (select i.full_name 
        from family_table i 
        where v.family_id = i.family_id 
        LIMIT 8,1) as voter_09
from family_table v
group by family_id
```

Comment: I assume you have tried indexing?

Comment: @bassick Why must all the members be in the same row with different columns?

Comment: blackpen - I indexed the "family_id" column and my original query from above worked blazingly fast. Thanks!!

Comment: @Pachonk - I have a table editor that my Users use. I will actually have another corresponding column displayed with each family member so my users can edit info for each household and member all on the same "Household Edit Page". So it is important that all family members and whatever corresponding info I choose be queried as one row in order  to fit my Table Editor layout. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What if a family has > 8 people? I think the subquery method you're using isn't a scalable method for getting all family members.

That being said, I think you do have 2 options here:

Option 1 ([GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)):

```
SELECT v.family_id, GROUP_CONCAT(v.fullname) as voters
FROM family_table v
GROUP BY v.family_id
```

And here's a SQLFiddle to show you the result set: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6da73/1

Option 2 (Return all voters as individual rows, directly next to each other):

```
SELECT v.family_id, v.fullname
FROM family_table v
ORDER BY v.family_id:
```

Option 3 (not my favorite, could be done better, but I believe it should be faster than the subqueries you're using):

```
SELECT v.family_id, v.fullname, v2.fullname, v3.fullname, v4.fullname, v5.fullname,
  v6.fullname, v7.fullname, v8.fullname
FROM family_table v
LEFT JOIN family_table v2 ON v2.family_id = v.family_id AND v2.fullname != v.fullname
LEFT JOIN family_table v3 ON v3.family_id = v.family_id AND v3.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname)
LEFT JOIN family_table v4 ON v4.family_id = v.family_id AND v4.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname, v3.fullname)
LEFT JOIN family_table v5 ON v5.family_id = v.family_id AND v5.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname, v3.fullname, v4.fullname)
LEFT JOIN family_table v6 ON v6.family_id = v.family_id AND v6.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname, v3.fullname, v4.fullname,
                                                                            v5.fullname)
LEFT JOIN family_table v7 ON v7.family_id = v.family_id AND v7.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname, v3.fullname, v4.fullname,
                                                                                v5.fullname, v6.fullname)
LEFT JOIN family_table v8 ON v8.family_id = v.family_id AND v8.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname, v3.fullname, v4.fullname,
                                                                                v5.fullname, v6.fullname, v7.fullname)
LEFT JOIN family_table v9 ON v9.family_id = v.family_id AND v9.fullname NOT IN (v.fullname,  v2.fullname, v3.fullname, v4.fullname,
                                                                                v5.fullname, v6.fullname, v7.fullname, v8.fullname)
GROUP BY v.family_id;
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6da73/2))

*Note: For the NOT IN part, if you have a primary key on each row, you should use that primary key as the not in, as it will be far better indexed (and there's a small chance 2 people in 1 family have the same name)*

Comment: Thx for reply. I know my query only covers 9 people. I just wanted to show an example.  "Group_concat" and multiple rows doesn't work for me. I need all members in their own columns in the same row.

Comment: I added a third option. It's still inefficient, but I think it should work better than many many subqueries.

Comment: Pachonk - I got this error. (#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay)

Comment: It's complaining that you're joining too many rows with this query. You can take the suggestion of the error, or add a where/limit. It's not the prime solution, but it should be faster than your original query while it works. Out of curiosity, how many rows are we trying to SELECT?

Comment: When I ran my original query, post-indexing, I ended up with over 8000 unique household rows (some had multiple family members, some did not. but the output had all unique "family_id" values.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the column "family_id" made my original query run blazingly fast. Thanks @blackpen for your comment.

I would stil, at some time, like to figure out a query that would cover any number of family members and not just have a huge number of subqueries that I hardcode.  But this absolutely works for now. Thanks @Pachonk for the input.

Comment: Columns can never be dynamic, only rows can. You would have to use one of the two queries from above if you wanted to allow it to support any number of family members.

Comment: If you are using another language, you could use group concatenate to allow for dynamic range of family members. It would be a faster query and you could use explode to turn the comma separated list into an array. (of course, most other languages have alike functions.

Comment: However, I am glad to hear the index helped.

Comment: True. I'm tired and not thinking straight. Haha. I think I'm good for now with my original query. I'll try to edit your 3rd query this weekend. Thanks again for the input.